# approximating unbounded integral in higher dimension

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In multivariable calculus, I usually encounter this: if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we can define $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} f(x) dx = \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{B(0,R)} f(x) dx$ if this limit exists where $B(0,R)$ is the ball centered at $0$ of radius $R$. However, for the case $n=1$, this is not true: consider the function $f(x)=x$. We know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x dx$ is undefined, but $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{B(0,R)} x dx = 0$. Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: Technically speaking what you have written is not the definition of an integral over $\Bbb{R}^n$, it is the Cauchy Principal Value. Really if the integral exists, then the limit over all infinitely expanding shapes should be equal so the implication goes one way only - the existence of the second does not imply the existence of the first but vice versa is true.

Comment: I have seen proof that want to integrate some function f over some unbounded domain, and they use $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int_{B(0,R)} f(x) dx$ to then use divergence theorem, for example. So by what you said, the argument is technically missing, first you need to prove that the integral over the unbounded domain must be the same no matter how you grow the bounded domain? How would you prove something like that?

Comment: The same way you would prove any limit exists - some sort of inequality argument, as taking limits along different "paths" (different expanding solids) would not be enough. You can get around this sometimes by integrating a strictly nonnegative function - their principal value will always imply the existence of the integral in general. This nonnegative function is either your integrand or a comparison function to bound another integral.